# My website url keeps referring to the template folder

Tags: joomla-3.5

I am using Joomla version 3.6.4. Currently my urls are long and reffereing to the template theme.

Example: http://multitrix.co.uk/chairman-quickstart-package/index.php/corporate-home-3

I want it to just say: www.multitrix.co.uk

What do I need to do to change this?

Answer (score 1):

This is not the template folder, it is that you have installed a quick-start package inside the folder chairman-quickstart-package of your document root.

You simply need to move this joomla installation from that folder to the doc root of your hosting account (usually called public_html in cPanel hosting).

Refer to this Q/A to learn how to do this:
**[How to move my site from subfolder to root?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/5207/how-to-move-my-site-from-subfolder-to-root)**

Furthermore this is not a site, is a demo, so its deeper urls are sample urls to sample pages that have nothing to do with what your final urls/pages will look like.